# Move mouse cursor to coordinates that are imported from a text file

Tags: python, coordinates, cursor-position, pynput

I am quite new to Python! I have a text file with some x,y coordinates like so:

```
1126 , 600
850 , 254
190 , 240
549 , 109
```

I am using Pynput to move the mouse to a specific position, such as

```
mouse.position=(300,500)
```

I want to be able to have the code read coordinates from the text file "XY_test.txt" so it can print the coordinates and also move the cursor to them.

```
try:
    file=open("E:\\XY_test.txt",'r')
    coords=file.readlines()
    for i in range (1,2):
        print(coords[i])
        mouse.position=(coords[i])
finally:
    file.close()
```

With this code I can successfully print the coordinates, but the cursor does not move to the desired position. Instead the cursor goes to the position (1,1). It seems that there is a problem with the formatting of the "mouse.position=(coords[i])" line. It expects a value of (x,y), but it apparently reads "1126,600" and puts the first digit as an x-value and the second digit as a y-value. I discovered this when I used "mouse.move(coords[i])" in the place of "mouse.position=(coords[i])" as seen below.

```
>>> try:
    file=open("E:\\XY_test.txt",'r')
    coords=file.readlines()
    for i in range (1,2):
        print(coords[i])
        mouse.move(coords[i])
finally:
    file.close()


1126 , 600
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#181>", line 6, in <module>
    mouse.move(coords[i])
TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dy'
```

I am not sure how to properly have the code read lines of the text file and use them properly as coordinates.

Comment: When you read from the file is it a string or a number?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  In the loop, print `coords[i]` - what happens? why?

Comment: `...don't know what to try next` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your list of coords will look something like this:

`coords=['1126 , 600', 850 , 254', '190 , 240', '549 , 109']`

So what you're actually passing to `mouse.move()` is:

`mouse.move('1126, 600')` instead of `mouse.move(1126, 600)`.

What you need to do is `split` each coord by `' , '`, cast each side to `int`, then pass those as two separate arguments.

Comment: @GinoCheeseSteaks Glad it worked! If the problem is solved, please hit the checkmark on my answer to mark it as correct. Cheers :)